# Building mapnik 3.0 in raspberry pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, postgis, mapnik

I have the latest version of postgis (2.1.8) in my raspberry pi. I could not use the default mapnik version (2.0) available in raspberry pi packages because the newer postgis does not have the functions that the old mapnik looks for.

So, I tried to compile the latest version of mapnik (3.0) . The configure was successful finding all required dependencies. But when I do make, it fails for insufficient memory. Then I increased the swap to 2GB. It still fails for insufficient memory.

I am wondering if there is a way to compile mapnik at smaller steps that do not require so much memory at once.

Comment: What functions was the old mapnik looking for? You might be able to install them from `legacy.sql` shipped with PostGIS 2.1

Comment: Mike - Thanks for the clue. It resolved the problem. ( It was failing for missing AsBinary). If you could post this comment as an answer, I will accept it. Not sure if I can do this by myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Legacy PostGIS functions without a `ST_` prefix can be loaded on top of any PostGIS database by loading the `legacy.sql` enabler script that shipped with PostGIS, in the `contrib` share folder. Run it like this:

```
psql -d [yourdatabase] -f legacy.sql
```

Find more on legacy.sql in [Chapter 2 of the PostGIS manual](http://postgis.net/docs/postgis_installation.html).